# How to debug HTTP headers of request/responses performed during SBT publish?

Tags: sbt, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to find out why I can't publish scala packages to a Maven repository (Azure Artifacts, see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5483)

I'm receiving a 203 HTTP code which causes SBT to fail the publish task.

I'm hoping to get additional info by inspecting the `Warning` HTTP header that - hopefully - Microsoft has added to the HTTP response but can't figure out how to configure SBT to print them on the console (setting `logLevel := Level.Debug` didn't help)

Answer (score 0):

The error 203: Non-Authoritative Information seems like a authorization issue.

Please try encoding your PAT to base64 format to use Basic Authentication. Please check below example to get the BASE64 authorization with PAT in powershell script.

```
$PAT="***"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
```

Please check out this similar [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/699412/203-non-authoritative-information-with-bearer-toke.html), and [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/630622/azure-devops-api-returns-203-after-attempting-to-p.html) to get a correct basic authorization string

Hope above helps!

Comment: Although 203: Non-Authoritative information _seems_ like an authorization issue - but this is not the case here. After some digging I get 203 when using an invalid PAT or no PAT at all (should be 401), when using a PAT without publishing permission (should be 403), when using a valid path with an invalid version number for my artifact (should probably be 400 or some other exotic HTTP code). Could you folks at MS please respond with appropriate HTTP codes please :) ?

Comment: Moreover this question is more about configuring SBT to inspect HTTP response than authenticating against Azure Artifacts. I know I can authenticate, it _used to work._ However, now that it doesn't anymore, I'd like to understand _why_ it doesn't, hence the need to print HTTP response body and headers.